# Session library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I want to check if the user is loggedin in codeigniter and set this into `config/routing.php` the nedded controller as default and redirect all request depending on what level of access has the user.

I make in `config/routing.php` until now something like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE){
    $route['default_controller'] = $_SESSION['class'];
    $route['(.*)']               = $_SESSION['class']."/$1";
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'first';
}
```

I tryed with `$this->session->userdata()` but i recive error because i think the `config/autoload.php` or session is loaded after `config/routing.php`.

Any ideeas ?

Answer (score 2):

Load session in codeigniter like this

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

But its better to load in `autoload.php`.

its not `$_SESSIONS` its `$_SESSION`

```
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE){
    $route['default_controller'] = $_SESSION['class'];
    $route['(.*)']               = $_SESSION['class']."/$1";
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'first';
}
```

in codeigniter use like hits,

```
if($this->session->userdata("loggedin") == TRUE)
{
    $route['default_controller'] = $this->session->userdata("class");
    $route['(.*)'] = $this->session->userdata("class")."/$1";
} else {
    $route['default_controller'] = 'first';
}
```

Comment: Sorry typo, but when i use this is it gives to me this error `Message: Undefined variable: _SESSION`

Comment: Ok i tryed this too :) and i recived `Message: Undefined property: CI_Router::$session` i think because config/routes.php it loads before session library

Comment: I have in config/autoload.php session library loaded `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');`

Comment: have you set encryption key for session in `config.php`??

Comment: Yes i have setted the encryption key in config/config.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96368/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-cosmin).

Comment: How about initializing session in pre_system hook? I found [here](http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/php/how_codeigniter_works) interesting article (for CI2 though).

Comment: @Tpojka i have added a answer to this problem, i seen too late this comment, i think it can work and with hook but i don't use very mutch.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have made to work without errors. I have commented two lines from `system/libraries/Session/Session.php`:

```
session_start();  (Line:140)
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);   (Line:313)
```

And added to `appliction/config/routes.php` the `session_start()`. It works witout error.

I hope helps anyone.